# Loop items in list of user defined table types

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops, types

I have simple table with 2 columns CarId int, primary key and CarName, varchar.

I need to create a stored procedure which accepts a list of cars. If car with `CarId` doesn't exist, I want to insert that car, and if already exists, I want to update it.

I created a user-defined table type `CarType`:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CarType
AS TABLE
(
    CARID int null,
    CARNAME varchar(800) not null,
);
```

and stored procedure `InsertCars`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCars
    @Cars AS CarType READONLY
AS
    DECLARE @CarCount INT = 0;
    DECLARE @Counter INT = 0;
BEGIN
    SET @CarsCount = (SELECT COUNT(CarId) FROM @Cars);

    WHILE(@Counter < @CarsCount)    
        BEGIN TRY
            --how get item from list Cars?
            @CurrentCar = Cars(@Counter)

            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Cars WHERE CarsId = CurrentCar.CarId)
                --if doesn’t exist insert
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO CARS(CARID, CARNAME)
                    SELECT * FROM @CurrentCar;
                END

             ELSE
                BEGIN
                    --if exist update
                END
             END

            SET @Counter= @Counter + 1; 
        END TRY

        BEGIN  CATCH
            Print (ERROR_MESSAGE());
        END CATCH
END
```

I don't know how get current car in loop from list of cars (parameter `Cars` in the stored procedure).

Or some elegant solution for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you may get rid of loop here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCars
    @Cars AS CarType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE c
    SET c.CARNAME = c2.CARNAME
    FROM Cars c
        JOIN @Cars c2 on c2.CARID = c.CARID;

    INSERT INTO Cars(CARID, CARNAME)
    SELECT c.CARID, c.CARNAME
    FROM @Cars c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Cars WHERE CARID = c.CARID);

END
```

or (using `merge` construct):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCars
    @Cars AS CarType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE Cars AS target
    USING (SELECT CARID, CARNAME FROM @Cars) AS source (CARID, CARNAME)
    ON (target.CARID = source.CARID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET CARNAME = source.CARNAME
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (CARID, CARNAME)
        VALUES (source.CARID, source.CARNAME);

END
```

Comment: @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN, I don't think that difference between the two will be dramatic, merge is quite comparable to update/insert (see [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/MERGE/103127/)). Use which one you like better, or which one is more clear to you.